# Clang error while installing QuickCheck for GHC 7.8.3 on OS X Yosemite 10.10 (14A389)

Tags: haskell, clang, cabal, osx-yosemite, quickcheck

While installing the `QuickCheck` for Haskell GHC 7.8.3 on a OS X Yosemite 10.10 (14A389) system running on a Mac Pro 2013 with Xcode 6.1 (6A1052d), I'm running into the following clang error:

```
   $ cabal install QuickCheck
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring primitive-0.5.4.0...
Building primitive-0.5.4.0...
Preprocessing library primitive-0.5.4.0...
[ 1 of 10] Compiling Data.Primitive.Internal.Compat ( Data/Primitive/Internal/Compat.hs, dist/build/Data/Primitive/Internal/Compat.o )
[ 2 of 10] Compiling Data.Primitive.MachDeps ( Data/Primitive/MachDeps.hs, dist/build/Data/Primitive/MachDeps.o )
[ 3 of 10] Compiling Data.Primitive.Internal.Operations ( Data/Primitive/Internal/Operations.hs, dist/build/Data/Primitive/Internal/Operations.o )
[ 4 of 10] Compiling Control.Monad.Primitive ( Control/Monad/Primitive.hs, dist/build/Control/Monad/Primitive.o )
[ 5 of 10] Compiling Data.Primitive.Types ( Data/Primitive/Types.hs, dist/build/Data/Primitive/Types.o )
[ 6 of 10] Compiling Data.Primitive.Array ( Data/Primitive/Array.hs, dist/build/Data/Primitive/Array.o )

Data/Primitive/Array.hs:32:1: Warning:
    The import of ‘Control.Monad.ST’ is redundant
      except perhaps to import instances from ‘Control.Monad.ST’
    To import instances alone, use: import Control.Monad.ST()
[ 7 of 10] Compiling Data.Primitive.ByteArray ( Data/Primitive/ByteArray.hs, dist/build/Data/Primitive/ByteArray.o )
[ 8 of 10] Compiling Data.Primitive.Addr ( Data/Primitive/Addr.hs, dist/build/Data/Primitive/Addr.o )
[ 9 of 10] Compiling Data.Primitive   ( Data/Primitive.hs, dist/build/Data/Primitive.o )
[10 of 10] Compiling Data.Primitive.MutVar ( Data/Primitive/MutVar.hs, dist/build/Data/Primitive/MutVar.o )
ld: library not found for -lgmp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Failed to install primitive-0.5.4.0
Configuring random-1.1...
Building random-1.1...
Preprocessing library random-1.1...
[1 of 1] Compiling System.Random    ( System/Random.hs, dist/build/System/Random.o )
ld: library not found for -lgmp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Failed to install random-1.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
QuickCheck-2.7.6 depends on random-1.1 which failed to install.
primitive-0.5.4.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
random-1.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
tf-random-0.5 depends on random-1.1 which failed to install.
```

It seems that the dynamic library `gmp` is missing. Does somebody have found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Same here. Just got the Yosemite yesterday. When will I learn not to early adopt OS X upgrades.

Comment: Try: `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Absolutely, that was it. Thanks @MichaelFox, I totally forgot about the command line tool installation.  Please submit that as your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MichealFox said in his comment, installing command line tools resolves this issue.

```
xcode-select --install
```

It also resolves problems with many other `cabal` packages depending on `gmp`/`lgmp` library.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (in my case compiling [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/installing.html) on a Centos 7 machine).

The `gmp` RPM was installed but not the `gmp-devel` RPM (which contains headers, linkable libraries, etc). This fixed it:

```
yum install gmp-devel
```